# Cannot access backend sevices in React App using GKE Ingress

Tags: reactjs, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a React application that I have been trying to run on GKE for weeks now but I cannot figure out the the GKE Ingress. There are a total of 7 microservices running including the React App.

My React App makes 4 API calls in total

```
"/posts/create"      //creates a new post
'/posts/comments/*'  //adds a comment to a post
'/posts'             // gets posts+comments, returns empty object since no posts are created
'/posts/save'        // saves post to cloudSQL
```

The application uses an event bus that handles communication between the different microservices so I created a ClusterIP service for each app and created additional NodePort services to use on the Ingress. After the Ingress is created I can access the React App but it says all of the backend services are unhealthy and I can't access them. I have tried calling the API's in several ways through the React Client including (calls // error in Chrome console

```
"http://query-np-srv:4002/posts" //Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
"http://10.96.11.196:4002/posts"(this is the endpoint for the service) //xhr.js:210 GET http://10.96.11.196:4002/posts net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
"http://posts.com/posts // GET http://posts.com/posts 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

If i run any of the follwoing commands from the client pod I get an object returned as intended

```
curl query-srv:4002/posts
curl 10.96.12.242:4002/posts
curl query-np-srv:4002/posts
```

The only way I have been able to get this application to actually work on GKE is by exposing the client, posts, comments, and query pods on LoadBalancers and hard coding the LB IP's into the API calls, which cannot be a best practice. At least this way I know the project is functional and leads me to believe this is an ingress issue

Here is my [Github repo for project](https://github.com/CBoton/blog2)

All of the yaml files are located in the infra/k8s folder and I am using the test.yaml to deploy the ingress, not the ingress-srv.yaml. Also, I am not using skaffold to deploy so that can be ignored as it is not causing the issues. If anyone can figure this out I would be very appreciative.

Comment: If after you create the ingress object the backends services are unhealthy, you need to review your Health checks. Did you review if GKE created Health checks for each backend service? Health checks connect to backends on a configurable, periodic basis. Each connection attempt is called a probe. Google Cloud records the success or failure of each probe. Google Cloud considers backends to be unhealthy when the unhealthy threshold has been met.

Comment: Unhealthy backends are not eligible to receive new connections; however, existing connections are not immediately terminated. Instead, the connection remains open until a timeout occurs or until traffic is dropped.

Comment: @Ismael Clemente Aguirre, yes there are health checks associated with the services. I just don't understand why they are "unhealthy" when they are running as intended or how to get them in a healthy state

Comment: I was able to make changes to the health checks and now 2 of the 4 unhealthy services are healthy. I added the path to the health check and that seemed to do the trick, just wondering why it only worked for 2 of the 4. The query service is actually responding with the empty object in chrome now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after you create the ingress object the backends services are unhealthy, you need to review your Health checks. Did you review if GKE created Health checks for each backend service?

> Health checks connect to backends on a configurable, periodic basis.
> Each connection attempt is called a probe. Google Cloud records the
> success or failure of each probe. Google Cloud considers backends to
> be unhealthy when the unhealthy threshold has been met. Unhealthy
> backends are not eligible to receive new connections; however,
> existing connections are not immediately terminated. Instead, the
> connection remains open until a timeout occurs or until traffic is
> dropped.

Comment: So the default GKE health checks use the root path ( / ) for the health check. The applications I was running don't use / other than the index page of the React App so thats why that one was the only one to work initially. I added the /posts path to my query service health check which is a get method then that one went from unhealthy to healthy. I tried adding the /posts/create path to the posts app and /posts/saves to the saves app but those are both post methods and didn't change them to healthy.

Comment: I then changed the path to /posts in the posts app which is a get method that just returns an empty object and guess what, it turned to healthy aftert that. I added the same method to my save application and changed the path in the HC and now my project is fully functional. I guess each service just has to have a get method so the health check can get that 200 response and be considered healthy? Thanks Ismael for pointing me in the direction of the health check